# Can't bring BIOS up now that I have Ubuntu installed (side-by-side with Windows Vista)

Tags: system-installation

I recently installed Ubuntu Desktop alongside Windows and I like Ubuntu so much, I want to reinstall it as the sole operating system on my laptop.  The dvd I burned won't boot up automatically so I'm trying to get into BIOS to make that happen, but I can't get the BIOS screen when I start the computer.  Instead, the screen that allows me to boot Windows or Ubuntu appears.  Tried hitting F8 but it doesn't present options for the dvd bootup.  Can anyone help me with this?  I'm computer-use literate but not highly technical.  Thx. :)

Comment: There is usually some key press soon after start-up to get into the BIOS but it varies between models.  On my laptop its F2 -- Let us know make and model of your PC and somebody here may have experience.

Comment: It's a Toshiba Satellite U205-S5057 laptop. I checked the manual online and it says F12 to access, but I practically dance on the dang key and there is no response.  It seems that installing Ubuntu has hindered access somehow. I considered uninstalling it but can't find the "easy" way to do this that Ubuntu advertised.  Really don't want to get into recovery discs and the like...

Comment: It's very very unlikely that Ubuntu installation has affected this. You can try patting on the key for BIOS Setup (F2?) or Boot Priority Menu (F12?) with DVD inserted immediately after switching your computer on.

Comment: Did it.  Not much luck, I'm afraid, but thanks.  I  tried every "F"-ing (ha ha) key but none worked.  I ended up erasing the hard disk and installed Ubuntu from a dvd.  It took a long time but was easy and I could walk away during the installation without a zillion prompts to hold things up.  Thanks so much for being there - you're awesome!  :)

Answer (score 1):

Some newer computers have a **Boot menu** as well as a **BIOS setup menu**.

For example, some computers use **F2** for BIOS setup and **F12** for Boot menu, which allows you to boot the computer from CD/DVD-ROM or USB drive instead of HDD.

Some older computers which don't have **Boot** menu, may use keys such as **Delete** or **Esc** as well to enter into **BIOS** menu.

You should consult your computer or motherboard manual to see which keys you should press at the very beginning of the boot process to have it displayed or try and find it by trial-and-error.

Or you might get more specific info from users of the same computer brand/model if you specify your computer (or motherboard) brand/model.

Comment: Thanks.  I found a manual online - it's F12.  Unfortunately none of the F-keys worked, including F12, so I ended up erasing the hard drive and starting over.  Many thanks for your help tho! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just a wild shot here, but I found this to be useful.

Just in case you have a Toshiba laptop which doesn't open the boot menu (caused by the *FastBoot* option turned on), you may reach it by doing a shutdown, press <kbd>F2</kbd> and turn on the laptop.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It varies on the computer, but it's usually either F2, F12 or DEL. Make sure you press this key right after POST (when the brand logo appears, not after that).

Answer (score 0):

neither ubuntu or windows has effect on BIOS
to get into BIOS you will have to turn on your computer and press F2 or Del depending on your motherboard
moreover, some computers use other key, try looking at your motherboard manual

Answer (score -2):

On modern computers, especially laptops, BIOS post is bypassed in order to boot faster. In order to access the BIOS settings, enter

sudo shutdown -H now

from a terminal window. When Ubuntu freezes, hold down the power button for at least 5 seconds. The BIOS settings should be accessible during the next power up.